# Evaluation of the series $S(\omega)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k {\alpha \choose k}\cos(k\omega)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I had a problem evaluating the series
\begin{equation}
S(\omega)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k {\alpha \choose k}\cos(k\omega),\quad 0<\alpha<2,\quad \omega\in(-\pi,\pi)
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
{\alpha \choose k}=\frac{\Gamma(1+\alpha)}{\Gamma(\alpha-k+1)\Gamma(k+1)}
\end{equation}
is the binomial coefficient generalized to non-integer.

Seems it is a bit like Fourier series. However the coefficients are strange. I have drawn the curve of $S(\omega)$ vs. $\omega$ and through visualization I thought that $S(\omega)$ may be a well behaved function which has a simpler form.

Can you help me find a simple, equivalent expression to the above series? If that doesn't exist, is there an approximation to the sum?

Any answer would be appreciated.

P.S.:

Some answers given are concerned with complex numbers $(1-e^{i\omega})$. As far as I know, $(1-e^{i\omega})^\alpha$ is a multi-valued function. It is not convenient for evaluation in Matlab.

Is there an equivalent function that only involves real numbers?

Comment: Note that $\cos(k\omega)$ is the real part of $e^{i k\omega}$ with $k$ an integer. Try thinking about this as a sum in $z=e^{i \omega}$...

Comment: I started writing an answer as follows: $\displaystyle S(\omega) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k {\alpha \choose k}\cos(k\omega)$ $\displaystyle{} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k {\alpha \choose k}\operatorname{Re}(e^{ik\omega})$
$\displaystyle{} = \Re\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty {\alpha \choose k} (-e^{i\omega})^k\right) = \operatorname{Re}\left( ( 1-e^{i\omega} )^\alpha \right)$.  Then I thought there might be some complications and I didn't finish it.  But I think it might work if pursued a bit further. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: The simplest way to finish the algebra in @MichaelHardy's approach is to factor out something that's obviously real (and being able to spot that is a good trick to know).

Comment: @ Michael Hardy @ Semiclassical Is there a real function that equals? (I have modified my post)

Comment: Looking at it more carefully, it's more thorny than I gave credit for due to $\alpha$ not being an integer. Out of curiousity, what value of $\alpha$ did you use when plotting?

Comment: @Semiclassical I have tested $\alpha=0.1,0.2,\cdots,1.9$.

Comment: Ok. Note that those are all rational values with denominator 10. That means that in every case $(1-e^{i\omega})^\alpha$ is at most 10-valued. I'm not certain, but I wouldn't be surprised that taking $\alpha$ to be real---say, $\pi/4$---gives results which are a bit hairier since $(1-e^{i\omega})^\alpha$ will be infinitely multi-valued.

Comment: Yes. You are right. I referred to my textbook and found that the number of values is infinite if $\alpha$ is not rational. That is the question. Because I want to study the series in a simpler way, say, as a combination of elementary functions such as $x^a$, $e^x$, $\sin(x)$ etc.

Comment: @MichaelHardy The complications are involving convergence issue. The identity will be only valid if convergence is established. That can be done by Abel's theorem.

Comment: @i707107 Can you say more about establishing the convergence? I am only familiar with Abel's theorem when the series is power series.

Comment: @ecook The power series involving binomial coefficient, has radius of convergence $1$. This can be achieved by ratio test. The convergence on the unit circle can be achieved by Abel's theorem. $\sum_{n\leq x} z^n$ is bounded when $z\neq 1$ and the binomial coefficient $\binom{\alpha}{k}$ converges to zero. Also, this power $\alpha$ function is actually not multi-valued. It is  $\exp(\alpha\log (1-e^{iw}))$.

Comment: @i707107 Can I conclude that the power series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty   \left( \alpha \atop k \right)z^k$ converges for all $|z|\le1$?

Comment: @ecook As far as I know for $0<\alpha<2$ as in your assumption, the power series converges for all $|z|\leq 1$, $z\neq 1$. For $z=1$, the analysis should be more careful, but I did not work it out yet. Also, there would be more to be said about $\alpha$. Such as, what are the set of all $\alpha$'s such that $\sum_k\binom{\alpha}{k} z^k$ converges for all $|z|\leq 1$, $z\neq 1$?

Comment: @i707107 Can the convergence at $z=1$ be evaluated as $\sum_{k=0}^\infty{\alpha \choose k}z^k=\sum_{k=0}^\infty{\alpha \choose k}=(1+1)^\alpha=2^\alpha$? Can you show how the series is evaluated at $|z|=1$ and $z\ne1$?

Comment: Got something from an answer below?

Comment: For integer $\alpha$ it is useful to employ the generating function $g(z)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } z^n S(\omega ,n)=\frac{1-2 z \sin ^2\left(\frac{\omega }{2}\right)}{1-4 z (1-z) \sin ^2\left(\frac{\omega }{2}\right)}$

Comment: For half integer $\alpha$ I find after some simple but lengthy calculations this generating function $g\left(z,\alpha \to \frac{1}{2}\right)\text{:=}\sum _{m=0}^{\infty } z^m S\left(\omega ,\frac{m}{2}\right)\\=\frac{1-z \sqrt{2 \sin \left(\frac{\omega }{2}\right)} \cos \left(\frac{\omega -\pi }{4}\right)}{1-2 \sqrt{2} z \sqrt{\sin \left(\frac{\omega }{2}\right)} \cos \left(\frac{\omega -\pi }{4}\right)+2 z^2 \sin \left(\frac{\omega }{2}\right)}$

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $\omega\ne0$. 
Then $1-\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\omega}\ne0$ and users @MichaelHardy and @i707107 explained in comments why 
$$
S(\omega)
=
\Re\exp(\alpha\cdot\mathrm{Log}(1-\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\omega})),
$$ 
under the condition that 
$$
\left|\alpha\cdot\arg(1-\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\omega})\right|
\lt
\pi,
$$ 
where $\arg$ denotes the principal argument, with values in $(-\pi,\pi]$, and $\mathrm{Log}$ denotes the principal branch of the complex logarithm, defined on $\mathbb C\setminus\mathbb R_-$ by the identity 
$$
\mathrm{Log}(r\mathrm e^{\mathrm it})
=
\ln(r)+\mathrm i\mathrm t,
\quad 
r\gt0,
\quad 
|t|\lt\pi.
$$
Thus, the main task is to identify $z=1-\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\omega}$ as $z=r\mathrm e^{\mathrm it}$ with $r\gt0$ and $|t|\lt\pi$, and to check the argument condition. 
To do so, note that 
$$
z
=
\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\omega/2}\cdot(\mathrm e^{-\mathrm i\omega/2}-\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\omega/2})
=
-2\mathrm i\,\sin(\omega/2)\,\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\omega/2},
$$ 
hence 
$$
r
=
2\,|\sin(\omega/2)|,
\qquad
\mathrm e^{\mathrm it}
=
-\mathrm i\,\mathrm{sgn}(\omega)\,\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\omega/2}
=
\mathrm e^{\mathrm i(\omega-\mathrm{sgn}(\omega)\pi)/2}.
$$ 
This proves that $t=\frac12(\omega-\mathrm{sgn}(\omega)\pi)$ since this number is in the interval $(-\pi/\pi)$. 
Furthermore, separating the cases $\omega\gt0$ and $\omega\lt0$, one can see that $|t|\lt\pi/2$. 
Since $|\alpha|\lt2$, the argument condition holds and 
$$
S(\omega)
=
r^\alpha\,\Re\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\alpha t}
=
r^\alpha\,\cos(\alpha t),
$$
that is,

> $$
> S(\omega)
> =
> 2^\alpha\,\left|\sin\left(\tfrac12\omega\right)\right|^\alpha\,\cos\left(\tfrac12\alpha(\omega-\mathrm{sgn}(\omega)\pi)\right).
> $$

*Exercise:* 
Extend this formula to the case $\omega=0$. 
Check that this defines an even function on $(-\pi,\pi)$. 
When $\alpha=1$, check that the RHS is $2\sin^2(\omega/2)$ for every $\omega$ in $(-\pi,\pi)$ and explain why it ought to.

Comment: Thank you very much for your great answer.

Comment: Hmmm... Surely you recognized that sgn(ω) denotes **the sign** of ω?

Comment: I have answered your question below. By the way, I have another question. Why only considering principal branch?

Comment: Because this is the only way to make that the real part of the complex function one considers, indeed coincides with $S(\omega)$ in the question.

Comment: Still I am not quite clear. If all branches are considered, $(1-e^{i\omega})^\alpha=r^\alpha e^{i\alpha t}\cdot e^{i\alpha 2k\pi}$, $k=0, \pm 1,\pm 2,\cdots$ and $r$, $t$ are the same as you give in the answer. Why only considering the case $k=0$ ?

Comment: This is entirely answered by my LAST comment.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

If you replace $\cos(k\omega)$ by $\dfrac{{e^{ik\omega}+e^{-ik\omega}}}{2}$ or if you compute $$S(\omega)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k {\alpha \choose k}\cos(k\omega)$$ as being the real part of $$T(\omega)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k {\alpha \choose k}e^{i k \omega}$$ using the generalised binomial theorem, you end with $$S(\omega)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k {\alpha \choose k}\cos(k\omega)=\frac{1}{2} \left(\left(1-e^{i \omega}\right)^\alpha+\left(1-e^{-i \omega}\right)^\alpha\right)$$ which a real valued function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you have any idea of finding a real function equivalent?

Comment: It is a real valued function.

Comment: Can you give a hint on why it is a real valued? Looking at the equation it seems to me that the expression contains multi-valued complex term $(1-e^{i\omega})^\alpha$. Besides, how to evaluate the  expression numerically in Matlab? term by term?  Thank you

Comment: Sorry but I do not know Matlab.

Comment: That's OK. Thanks again. Do you have any idea on how to estimate the bounds of $S(\omega)$ for any fixed $\omega$?

Answer (score 0):

Use the identity

> $$\cos(k\omega) = \frac{e^{ik\omega}+e^{-ik\omega}}{2}$$

and the [Newton's generalised binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) as

> $$ S_1 = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k {\alpha\choose k}e^{ik\omega} = (1-e^{i\omega})^{\alpha}. $$

You do the rest of the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I have modified my question. Do you know what is the real function equivalent to the series?

Comment: The first identity has a typo. The approach using the second identity was underlined by others in comments. The whole is far from giving a full solution.

Comment: @Did: the typo was corrected. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for the answer given by @Did.

In this reply, I'll try to answer the exercise he proposes.

1. The formula 
   \begin{equation}
   S(\omega) = 2^\alpha|\sin(\omega/2)|^\alpha \cos\left[\frac{\alpha}{2}(\omega-\text{sgn}(\omega)\pi)\right]
   \end{equation}
   can be extended by defining $\text{sgn}(0) = \frac{1}{\alpha}$ such that $\omega=0$ is also included.
2. The formula is even because
   \begin{equation}
   \cos\left[\frac{\alpha}{2}(\omega-\text{sgn}(\omega)\pi)\right] = \cos(\alpha\omega/2)\cos(\alpha\text{sgn}(\omega)\pi/2)+\sin(\alpha\omega/2)\sin(\alpha\text{sgn}(\omega)\pi/2)
   \end{equation}
   and
   \begin{equation}
   \begin{split}
   &\cos(\alpha\text{sgn}(\omega)\pi/2)=\cos(\alpha\pi/2) ,\quad \omega>0\\
   &\cos(\alpha\text{sgn}(\omega)\pi/2)=\cos(\alpha\pi/2) ,\quad \omega<0\\
   &\sin(\alpha\text{sgn}(\omega)\pi/2)=\sin(\alpha\pi/2) ,\quad \omega>0\\
   &\sin(\alpha\text{sgn}(\omega)\pi/2)=-\sin(\alpha\pi/2) ,\quad \omega<0\\
   \end{split}
   \end{equation}
3. When $\alpha=1$, the formula becomes
   \begin{equation}
   S(\omega)=2|\sin(\omega/2)| \cos\left[(\omega-\text{sgn}(\omega)\pi)/2\right]
   \end{equation}
   and since
   \begin{equation}
   \begin{split}
   &\cos\left[(\omega-\text{sgn}(\omega)\pi)/2\right] = \cos(\omega/2-\pi/2)=\sin(\omega/2),\quad \omega>0\\
   &\cos\left[(\omega-\text{sgn}(\omega)\pi)/2\right] = \cos(\omega/2+\pi/2)=-\sin(\omega/2),\quad \omega<0\\
   \end{split}
   \end{equation}
   We conclude
   \begin{equation}
   S(\omega)=2\sin^2(\omega/2)
   \end{equation}